# В чем разница между «сдается мне» и «мне кажется»?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Хм, что-то капает, **сдается мне**, что мы где-то водопровод повредили.
>
> Хм, что-то капает, **мне кажется**, что мы где-то водопровод повредили.

Сдается мне, что выражение «мне кажется» встречается в десять раз чаще. Интересно, чем по смыслу и употреблению одно отличается от другого?

Answer (score 3):

По смыслу нет никаких отличий. По употреблению есть. Выражение "мне кажется" не имеет стилистических ограничений в употреблении, а "сдаётся мне" относится к разговорному стилю и его употребление в книжных стилях речи ограничено.

Answer (score 1):

[II. СДАВАТЬСЯ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/216298), сдаётся; безл.; несовер., *кому* (прост.). Думаться, казаться.
*Сдаётся мне, что он прав.*
|совер. **сдаться**, буд. не употр.; сдалось (устар. и прост.). *Сдалось мне, что он хитрит.*

Выражения **мне кажется** и **сдаётся мне** — это [синонимы](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/159923/%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F).
Думаю, что "сдаётся мне" несет в себе не только признак неуверенности в сказанном, но и оттенок сарказма, пренебрежения, самоиронии (в зависимости от контекста, конечно), а "мне кажется" является нейтральным (безэмоциональным, "всеупотребительным") выражением.

*Он водит тебя за нос, и, сдаётся мне, я знаю, в чём тут дело; И, сдаётся мне, господа, это всего лишь отвлекающий манёвр* (Т. Смирнова. Смерть на двоих).